# Generating a list of constants with a comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I was wondering how I would generate a list of constants with a python comprehension?

For instance, if I wanted to generate a list of 100 number 5s, how would I do this?

I'm having trouble understanding this because the way I keep track of the number of elements in the list is distinct from what I would like to output.

Comment: `[5] * 100` is the easy option for immutables.

Answer (score 5):

For immutable values, just *multiply* the list:

```
count = 100
[5] * count
```

For mutable values, use a list comprehension:

```
count = 100
[{'foo': 5} for _ in xrange(count)]
```

The `_` name here is just a convention; it means we are ignoring the loop target name in the loop itself.

Comment: I see, my list comprehension is a little more complicated than the constant multiplication, but the principle in the second example worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
my_list = [5 for _ in xrange(100)]
```

You can also do:

```
import itertools
my_list = list(itertools.repeat(5, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks Simeon! So how exactly does the '_' work? Is it just a counter that iterates through the range?

Comment: @goldisfine it's a variable but without giving it a name. You can also have something else there.